# Composite primary keys in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, composite-primary-key

I am trying to use http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/ in order to have composite primary keys in my activerecord models.

I already added `gem 'composite_primary_keys', '=3.1.0'` to my Gemfile.
Now I am trying to setup my first modelclass as follows.

```
class StringProperty < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_keys :entity_id, :property_id
    set_table_name "problem.string_property"
    attr_accessible :entity_id, :property_id, :value
end
```

But all I get is:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following will work I think.

```
require 'composite_primary_keys'
class StringProperty < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_keys = :entity_id, :property_id
    set_table_name "problem.string_property"
    attr_accessible :entity_id, :property_id, :value
end
```

Comment: Hm, now I am getting a new error on rails server.

composite_primary_keys.rb:37:in cannot load such file -- acitve_record/associations/association_prody.rb (LoadError)

Comment: Works now for me, was using an old version (3.x.x) this caused the LoadError

Comment: The repo is now at https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys

Comment: The documentation for the `composite_primary_keys` gem is rather sparse. I would instead suggest using Sequel, as suggested by Overbryd in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42185901/3017719.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only for unique constraint purposes use:

`class Field < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :input, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id,
        message: "one input per user" }
end`

source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html