# Is it possible to define composite primary key for table using active record?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rails-activerecord

I'm using ActiveRecord in a ruby project without rails. I need to define  composite primary  key for a table.Normally migration creates primary key automatically.  Is it possible to define my own composite primary key for a table using active record?

Comment: Why mark a question as duplicate if the original question doesn't have an answer? I just wasted my time looking the other question, in the other hand this question has two answers. I understand that the duplication is correct, but the mark confuses more than it helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some gems that give you this ability, such as [composite_primary_key](http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/).

I don't know if Rails 4 has added support for this, would be very interested to hear if it does.

Answer (score 1):

Question has been asked before, checkout: [How to set composite key in Rails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114627/how-to-set-composite-key-in-rails-application)

http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/ might also be useful.