# Rails 5 Postgres Duplicate Key Violation on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, model, constraints

In a Rails 5 app I create items and increment their position:

```
class ListItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list

  before_validation :ensure_position

  private
  def ensure_position
    self.position ||= self.class.where(list_id: list_id).maximum(:position).to_i + 1
  end
end
```

The index responsible for the duplicate violation is:

```
 t.index ["list_id", "position"]
```

I get a PG duplicate key violation on the :position column. Whenever multiple create are fired simultaneously, the maximum function returns the same position for multiple records.

I am new to thread safety and postgres locking in ruby on rails. Is there a way to lock or create a mutex on save action of the list item record so that the position gets incremented safely?

Comment: Why not use a sequence in the database like usual?

Comment: Sorry I am new to this, isn't a sequence a unique incremental colum? In my scenario :position is not unique, what is unique is [:list_id, :position].

Answer (score 0):

You want a composite primary_key which is not supported by Rails.

However, there is a [composite_primary_keys gem](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys) and a [blog post](http://www.bigastronaut.com/blog/2014/riding-rails-with-a-composite-primary-key) about using the gem.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am currently checking the gem and the blog post is interesting, but don't you think a whole gem is kind of an overkill for such a small part? In case you think about a workaround, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Well, Sami already have suggested a sequence like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36720571/4812102

"nothing prevents you from having what you think of a a composite primary key as an alternative key and have the Rails default PK (postgres: pseudotype 'serial' which draws its values from a sequence). Just make sure that you add a unique index for those columns that make up your key."